# Sed command returning "invalid command code"

Tags: sed

I'm trying to insert this text...

```
"error.emailNotActivated":"This email address has not been activated yet."
```

... at line number 5 using sed.

Here is my command so far

```sh
translated="This email address has not been activated yet.";
sed -i '' -e '5i\'$'\n''"error.emailNotActivated":'"\"$translated\"" local.strings;
```

I unfortunately keep getting the error message **"invalid command code T"**.
It seems that sed is interpreting the colon as part of a command.
Any suggestions how i can avoid this?

EDIT:
Seems like an update error (working with old file d'oh...)
the above expression works fine as do the other suggestions.

Comment: You need a space in the beginning: `-e'5i` should be `-e '5i`

Comment: @fedorqui ups little typo there. Unfortunately i still get the same error :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you fighting with sed for this? It's trivial in awk:

```
awk -v line='"error.emailNotActivated":"'"$translated"'"' '
NR==5{print line} {print}
' file
```

or:

```
awk -v line="\"error.emailNotActivated\":\"${translated}\"" '
NR==5{print line} {print}
' file
```

Comment: How can i insert a variable in to the sentence? line='"error.emailNotActivated":$translated'

Comment: you're welcome. sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text manipulation, just use awk as most sed language constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$ seq 1 5 > file

$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5

$ translated="\"error.emailNotActivated\":\"This email address has not been activated yet.\""

$ echo $translated 
"error.emailNotActivated":"This email address has not been activated yet."

$ sed -i "5i $translated" file

$ cat file
1
2
3
4
"error.emailNotActivated":"This email address has not been activated yet."
5
```